# Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $product_id ]] in class

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to delete products through a separate controller using livewire and I get this unable to resolve dependency error any help what I'm doing wrong here?

```
use App\Models\Products;
use Livewire\Component;

class Delete extends Component
{
    public function delete($product_id)
    {
        $product = Products::where('id', $product_id)->first();
        $product->delete();
    }
```

and this is my component

```
<div>
        <button wire:click="delete({{ $product_id ?? '' }})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete method in component receive a parameter, so in your blade you have to provide it through wire:click

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="delete({{ $product_id }})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Models\Products;
use Livewire\Component;

class Delete extends Component
{
    public function delete(Product $product)
    {
        //$product = Products::where('id', $product_id)->first();
        $product->delete();
    }
}
```

you comp it is better like that you don't need to pass an empty string implictBinding will resolve the product

```
<div>
        <button wire:click="delete({{ $product_id}})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
</div>
```